# Tell Grails not to create, alter nor update a domain classes table while bootstrapping

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, orm

I'm using Grails 1.3.8.

Among other domain classes I have one class that is mapped to a foreign database schema `YYYYY`.

```
class Borough implements Serializable {

    static mapping = {
        table name:'TABLE_NAME', schema: 'YYYYY'
        version false
        id(column:'GEMEINDE_NR')
        id generator:'assigned'
        cache 'read-only'
        kurzname(column: 'KURZNAME')
        langname(column: 'LANGNAME')
    }

    String kurzname
    String langname

    static constraints = {
        kurzname(nullable: true, blank:true, size:0..80)
        langname(nullable: true, blank:true, size:0..80)
    }
}
```

Via `dbCreate` set to `create-drop` in my config I want hibernate to create tables for all domain classes but the domain class `Borough` mentioned above since I'm not allowed to create, drop or update but to read from this table.

```
    dataSource {
        pooled = true
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        username="aaaa"
        password="bbb"
        dbCreate = "create-drop"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:CCC"
        dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
        default_schema="MYSCHEMA"
        properties {
                maxActive=50
                maxIdle=25
                minIdle=5
                initialSize=5
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=300000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=300000
                maxWait=10000
        }
    }
```

How can I tell Hibernate/Grails not to alter the specified Schema/Table?

Comment: You can't tell Grails to ignore just a single Domain class like that. Your only option is to turn your dbCreate to "none" and manage the schemas manually or using a plugin like database migrations.

Comment: Is it anyhow possible to assign different `dataSource`s to different domain classes? So I might set up two `dataSource`s, one with `create-drop` and one with `none`?

Comment: Great idea, and yes, there is: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources